# Use xcode debug socket program error

Tags: c++, xcode, sockets, permissions, bind

In xcode, I am trying to debug a socket program, but it doesn't work.

I think it is depending on root permissions?

How do I run this code using root permissions? thanks!

```
bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))
```

Comment: The port number is 80.

Comment: Change the port to one that doesn't require root?

Comment: Did you try the "Debug Process as root" option in the "Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme..." ?

Comment: Great!@martin-r,thanks for your answer,your are write!